# añadir a vector conjunto de caracteres de un string c++

Tags: c++, string

estoy intentando añadir a un **vector** una parte de un **string** concatenada con otro **string** pero no me es posible.

```
    vector <string> combf, combm;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        combf.push_back(father[i] + father[2]);
        combf.push_back(father[i] + father[3]);
        combm.push_back(mother[i] + mother[2]);
        combm.push_back(mother[i] + mother[3]);
    }
```

Me parece que es porque `father[i]` y los demás los toma como char y no como string, intenté solucionarlo con

```
string(father[i])+string(father[2])
```

y

```
string(father[i]+father[2])
```

y

```
strcat(father[i], father[2])
```

pero ninguna era una solución, pensé en hacer conversiones a char y char array pero necesito que el programa sea lo más corto, sencillo y rápido posible así que quiero ver si alguien tiene una solución a este problema sin la necesidad de estas conversiones.

Aunque la solución con conversiones es bienvenida :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con

```
vector <string> combf, combm;
for( int i = 0; i < 2; ++i ) {
    combf.push_back( string( 1, father[i] ) + father[2] );
    combf.push_back( string( 1, father[i] ) + father[3] );
    combm.push_back( string( 1, mother[i] ) + mother[2] );
    combm.push_back( string( 1, mother[i] ) + mother[3] );
}
```

Comment: Excelente sí funcionó, muchisímas gracias :)

Comment: Espera,  

      vector <string> combf, combm;
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
  combf.push_back(string() + father[i] + father[2]);
  combf.push_back(string() + father[i] + father[3]);
  combm.push_back(string() + mother[i] + mother[2]);
  combm.push_back(string() + mother[i] + mother[3]);
   }
Ese sí me funcionó perfectamente, el nuevo editado no

Comment: Me acabo de despertar. Necesito un café **urgente**. Prueba así. Mejor de esta forma, con solo 2 `string`.

Comment: jaja, sí, así también funciona, nuevamente muchas muchas gracias :)

Comment: Para eso estamos ;-)